# php mysql query encoding problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page with utf-8 encodin. Mysql is set to utf8_general_ci. 
Here is the query:

```
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8_general_ci");

               $query = "INSERT INTO newsbox VALUES ('null', '$zaglavie', '$nom_file_big', '$den', '$mesec', '$godina', '$zaglavie2', '$text', '$zaglavie3')";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

and cyrillic input text is inserted like ?????. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the mysql_query("SET ..") works as expected. Try setting the character set with mysql_set_charset().
Are you sure the text is inserted like that? If you're using the CLI mysql client with a wrong character set, display output may be faulty as well (that probably goes for retrieval via mysql_fetch_*() as well).

Comment: I am using my scripts for years and thats the first time I have such a problem :(

Answer (score 6):

What I tend to find solves things a lot is;

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Before any queries are performed.

The documentation recommends that you use `mysql_set_charset` but I often see that function missing.

```
if( function_exists('mysql_set_charset') ){
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db_con);
}else{
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db_con);
}
```

Comment: wow this worked for me! any idea why I didn't need to do this in the past?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the settings of your past environments - perhaps you got lucky.