# Saving Japanese characters with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm currently trying to save a japanese-character string with MySQL in PHP. The characters are saved as questionmarks. This is my query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO battles (basic_words) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($basic_words)."'");
```

The string "$basic_words" definitely contains japanese characters but they are not saved. The **coalition** for the row "basic_words" is **utf8_general_ci**

Comment: Where does `$basic_words` come from?

Comment: $basic_words comes from a class I created. Before checked the string before saving and the characters are correct/japanese

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[php mysql query encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741276/php-mysql-query-encoding-problem) suggests

```
$db_con= mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
if( function_exists('mysql_set_charset') ){
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db_con);
}else{
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db_con);
}
```

Also Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: not entirely sure, but setting "mysql_set_charset" and removing "set character set..." seems to have solved the issue. If I now remove "mysql_set_charset" it still works, weird but ok.

Comment: but I definitely have to include mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");